# How can I execute a call to the current process in a GenServer?

Tags: elixir, erlang-otp

I know I can call a GenServer like this

```
GenServer.call(pid, request)
# using a pid
```

or like this

```
GenServer.call(registered_name, request)
# if I registered the process with a name
```

But is there a way to excute the `GenServer.call` inside the module without knowing the pid/registered name?(ie is there something like `GenServer.call(__CURRENT_PROCESS__, request)`?)

Answer (score 5):

This will simply not work. A `GenServer.call` is simply sending a message to the given process and then waiting for another message (the reply), blocking the current process. If you send a message to `self` this way the process will not be free to handle that message as it will be blocked waiting for a reply. So the `call` will always time out.

What I suspect you need is just to extract the functionality you want into a function and directly call that. Alternatively you can send a `cast` to the current process, effectively telling it to do something "later".

Comment: Obrok I'm using the call to retrieve data. I remember I've read somewhere that it's recommeneded to use `cast` when you send data to a process without needing the response and `call` when you actually want to retrieve data from the other process.

Comment: Obrok I've actually read it in the Elixir Getting Started Guide [here](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/mix-otp/genserver.html#call-cast-or-info)

Comment: `call` is indeed used to retrieve data but not from the current process. If you're in a `GenServer`, chances are you're in a `handle_call`, `handle_cast` or `handle_info` callback - in all of these you have access to the state of the `GenServer` so there should be no reason to additionally request it from the same process.

Comment: Well yes but above I'm using `Genserver.call` inside a another function that I'll be using exclusively as an API for the outside world. I don't plan to use it inside the handlers. It's my bad that I didn't specified this. Besides this your statement makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure that's the best way to go but what you're looking for is [Kernel.self/0](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/v1.0/elixir/Kernel.html#self/0)

EDIT:

Per Sasha's comment the code would look like this:

```
GenServer.call(self, request)
```

EDIT:

Per the excellent point made by Pawel Obrok, you should never do a call to the current process.  If you need to send a message to the current process you should do it in this fasion:

```
GenServer.cast(self, request)
```

NB it's casting vs. calling.

Comment: Like Onorio said, you may use GenServer.call(self, request). Have a look into: 

http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/processes.html
or the Little Elixir and OTP Guide if you want a more in depth look on processes and the OTP platform.

Comment: @user3790827 I didn't say it's not a good idea.  I said I'm not sure that it's the best way to go.  It's really hard to say given that I have almost no context to your question.

Answer (score 4):

It depends. If you only start one `GenServer` process per node you can call it like:

```
@doc """
If you want to call the server only from the current module.
"""
def local_call(message) do
  GenServer.call(__MODULE__, message)
end
```

or

```
@doc """
If you want to call the server from another node on the network.
"""
def remote_call(message, server \\ nil) do
  server = if server == nil, do: node(), else: server
  GenServer.call({__MODULE__, server}, message)
end
```

If you have several processes from the same module, you need an extra identifier (For example, if you have an supervisor strategy `:simple_one_for_one` to generate `GenServer`s on demand).

For something like that I would recommend using:

- `:gproc` to name processes.
- `:ets` if you need extra information to identify your processes.

`:gproc` is awesome and it works with `GenServer`. You usually name your processes using an atom as a registered name. `:gproc` allows you to name your processes with an arbitrary term i.e. a tuple.

Let's say in my function call I have a complex identifier of my server like `{:id, id :: term}` where `id` can be a string, for example. I could start my `GenServer` like:

```
defmodule MyServer do
  use GenServer

  def start_link(id) do
    name = {:n, :l, {:id, id}}
    GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, %{}, name: {:via, :gproc, name})
  end
  (...)
end
```

And look up my process by something different than an atom, like I said before, a string for example. So if I start my server like:

```
MyServer.start_link("My Random Hash")
```

And I have a function like:

```
def f(id, message) do
  improved_call(id, message)
end

defp improved_call(id, message, timeout \\ 5000) do
  name = {:n, :l, {:id, id}}
  case :gproc.where(name) do
    undefined -> :error
    pid -> GenServer.call(pid, message, timeout)
end
```

You can use it to call processes like:

```
MyServer.f("My Random Hash", {:message, "Hello"})
```

If your naming process is more complex, you can use `:ets` to store a more complex state.

If you want to use `:gproc` you can add it to your `mix.exs` file like:

```
(...)
defp deps do
  [{:gproc, github: "uwiger/gproc"}]
end
(...)
```

On a side note, never, ever call `GenServer.call/3` from within `handle_call/3`. It will timeout and do a DOS on your other `GenServer.call`s. `handle_call/3` handles one message at the time.

Comment: This was a great and comprehensive answer. Thank you for sharing it.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand from your comment you're trying to write a public API function for your `GenServer` instead of making a `call` from within the `GenServer` process. AFAIK there isn't a way to do that without knowing the PID. However for `GenServers` of which you only create one instance an idiom for such a case exists: you name the sole instance of your `GenServer` with the name of the module implementing it. This can be done easily using the `__MODULE__` macro:

```
def start_link do
  GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, nil, name: __MODULE__)
end
```

And then in your API functions you just use `__MODULE__` in place of PID:

```
def api_function do
  GenServer.call(__MODULE__, :api_function)
end
```

This has the nice property that `__MODULE__` will always reflect the correct name of the enclosing module, even when you rename it.